# WPF multi select Combobox find what is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have setup a WPF combobox which a user can select many items within it using checkboxes. The UI looks good, but now I need to know what is ticked in C# so I can filter a Datagrid correctly.

Is there a way to do this with the code I already have below?

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbWorkFlowType" Width="120" Height="22" Margin="144,57,0,0"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
           <ComboBoxItem>
              <CheckBox x:Name="all">All</CheckBox>
           </ComboBoxItem>
           <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource WorkFlowTypeEnum}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
     </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Name="chkTask" Checked="CheckBox_Click" Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=all, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```

Even if I need to for loop around the combobox object to extract all the checked items, but I wouldn't know how to do this as the combobox doesn't use tickboxes in it's library so I don't think its possible?

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a list of lets say users for your combo box, on the user view model you would need a bool to store the selection. 
Then you would have to go through each user view model (or whatever the combo boxes source is) and look at the selection bool.

Comment: I agree with your logic and would have done this if it wasnt a Enum I am binding too. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: then you may possibly need a list of bools equal to the size of the list of Enums ? and then you can just use the list index to see if it is checked ? I'm not sure..